# Loading RadGrid NestedView on demand without using SqlDataSource

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I'm looking for an example on how to create a RadGrid NestedView template that loads the data when expanded.  All the examples I see use a SqlDataSource, but I would prefer to avoid that since I'm not using it on the parent grid (using the NeedsDataSource event).

This can't be that hard... I just can't get the databinding down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hook the DetailTableDataBind event of the telerik Ajax grid to bind the detail data for the nested view, Mike. I did that before as it is presented [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/detailtabledatabind/defaultcs.aspx) and it worked.